# Playing multiple youtube video in fragment with Viewpager

Tags: android, video, android-fragments, youtube, android-viewpager

I am trying to implement functionality like playing you-tube video in view-pager and when i swipe right or left it should play next or previous video according to my event.

To complete this what i am doing is, i have created fragment and adding view each time when i swipe view-pager, but i don't know why my code is not working.

Below is my code which i have tried.

```
private void setViewPager() {
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        mViewPager.addView(youFragment.getView());
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                posVideoViewPage = arg0;
                youFragment.playVideo(posVideoViewPage);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

            }
        });
    }
```

and here is **SectionPageAdapter**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = YoutubeFragment.newInstance(MainActivity.arrVideoYoutubeCode.get(position));
                break;
```

and so on.....